# Hook/Callback for HttpServletRequest complete

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I am setting a `ThreadLocal` variable in a `ServletFilter` for setting tenant in my web application. Now, I need to perform `ThreadLocal` cleanup at the end of request processing.

I think this is a common way of getting/setting the tenantId in a multi tenant application. 
But I am not able to identify a common place which can be used for performing this cleanup.

Is there any hook/callback that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

As you say that your are setting your ThreadLocal variable in a ServletFilter, you should to your cleanup in same filter. Something like :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain fc) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //set thread local variable
    // stuff ...
    try {
        // other stuff ...
        fc.filter(request, response)
        // still other stuff ...
    }
    finally {
        // cleanup ThreadLocal variable
    }
}
```